# GRUB won't show; Linux Mint and Windows 10 on separate drives

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, grub

I installed Linux Mint on one HDD and Windows 10 on another (Windows first), then I set the BIOS to boot the Linux disk first. It boots just fine, but it skips GRUB completely and just boots into Mint. I can boot into Windows by changing the BIOS back, but I'd much prefer to have grub handle that. I have already tried updating grub (with update-grub) and get the output:

```
Found linux image:  {some file}
Found initrd image:  {some file}
Found memtest86+ image:  {some elf file}
Found memtest86+ image:  {some bin file}
```

I think grub can't find Windows, but I'm open to any other ideas.

Update:

It shows the menu now but Windows 10 isn't on it.

Comment: Well i'm dumb, it wasn't. But it is now and win10 still isn't on it.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://askubuntu.com/q/758830)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases such problems are related to the fact, that Windows tends to do an MBR style partition scheme upon install and linux tends to do the GPT partition scheme. [What are these](https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)? Maybe you should post the output of

```
fdisk -l
```

on your linux partition to clarify your partitioning layout.

According to [this](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/GPT-disk-partition-manager/install-windows-10-on-gpt-partition.html) guide windows 10 even refuses to install on a drive that is GPT prepartitioned. I can't check that out because I have no Windows 10....

The solution that I would try is to explicitly switch off the UEFI boot mode in the BIOS settings and switch to Legacy boot mode. After that try to rerun the Linux installation (which now should take place using an MBR partition scheme).

When using Ubuntu you can explicitly see the difference of the bootloader theme when using the Legacy boot as opposed to UEFI boot mode... I guess you will notice the difference.

Comment: Note: all versions of Windows since Vista (and 64-bit XP on Itanium) can boot from GPT disks, and a UEFI system will not boot from an MBR disk [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn640535(v=vs.85).aspx#gpt_faq_xp64_boot)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have grub installed in MBR. Your MBR may have been corrupted. Use a windows bootable cd to recover the MBR using command.

It is a good practice to install Linux boot files on a separate partition and use esayBCD to create a boot entry.